# Why are these reviews rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have recently started reviewing the queues and I consider myself still a learner of the policies of SO.  I never realized that I could see the status of my suggested edits to the posts.

As I was going through the list of rejections to improve myself, I found a couple of rejections strange

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13214443) doesn't show my suggested edit at all!! I say this because it is still fresh in my mind that I added caption to the image along with code formatting blocks.  Thinking someone with higher reputation edited the post after me, I opened the question to see that there are no edits at all!!  Somehow, the question shows my edit as if it was asked by OP.

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13168797), I removed `sql-server` flag as if you read the question, it is very clear that the question has nothing to do with `sql-server`.  It is a pure `c#` question.  I'm not sure what is wrong in removing the unwanted tag from the question!!

I'm not worried about the rejections, but wanted to understand how these things work so that I can ensure my contributions are effective and meaningful without adding any noise.

EDIT:

Does it (This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit) mean a higher rep's edit always takes precedence and thinks more valuable than a edit suggested by lower rep person, even though the lower rep's edit seems to have equal quality edit?  [An example is here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13168536)

Comment: In one case, it was automagically rejected, likely due to another edit occurring that conflicted with it. The other was rejected by the OP directly, which they have full power to do. I don't think either of the two examples indicate that you did anything wrong.

Comment: To your edit: yes. This is done automatically, and there's no way for the system to determine the quality of the edit. People with 2k+ rep are trusted to know that their edit is of better quality.

Comment: *"Does it (This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit) mean a higher rep's edit always takes precedence and thinks more valuable than a edit suggested by lower rep person, even though the lower rep's edit seems to have equal quality edit? "* - well not exactly. Its basically the difference between your edit having to go through review or not - if you have 2k reputation that no longer is necessary. The fact that your edits are then applied immediately gives a false sense of precedence to edits waiting for approval. Its not any kind of status thing, just... programming.

Comment: I hope to have understand the difference between those two; but why do we still mark them as "rejected"; we could have programmed to reflect the status as "suppressed" or "ignored" some other status which might have been more meaningful and straight-forward!! I hope this question might not be the first, probably discussed somewhere!! It is very hard to count "which count towards my ban" and which don't... Is there a way instead of just going through each reject and see the comment?

Comment: @techspider look up meta questions about "disputed flag" to see some real confusion going on. The problem is not so much that the label is "rejected", its more that singular generalized words tend to simply not properly describe the truth. In any case I hope you only occasionally have a rejected edit, so it can't be too much of a problem to click through to see the full reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first edit was rejected as conflicting with a subsequent edit. If I had to guess, the OP didn't understand how the edit system worked and, while editing their question, saw your edits. They likely just copied and pasted them over. Alternatively, if the edits were small, typo fix type edits, the OP could have just seen them and edited it themselves without seeing your suggested edit.

You don't *see* an edit on that post because it was submitted within the five minute grace period. This further indicates it was likely small fixes that the OP caught onto themselves.

If the OP or a 2k+ rep users submits an edit after your suggested edit, yours will be rejected 100% of the time. However, this kind of edit rejection, does not count against you in terms of an edit ban.

The second case, the OP rejected your edit. They disagreed that the tag should be removed. You are correct that the tag does not appear to be needed, but the OP has a binding accept/reject vote on their own post. When it comes to an OP reject, it really can be hard to know if your edit really was off base or not. The only way to really get a feel for if the edit *was* bad is if other users had already reviewed it and had opted to reject it.

This reject *can* count against you for bans, but you have to be editing pretty poorly to get a ban. Given you are concerned with improving your editing abilities, I have a feeling you're editing well enough to not get banned.